# Why does aggregate polygons consistently error out?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, shapefile, geoprocessing, generalization

I'm using aggregate polygons on a dataset with three large study areas. It did not work. So I split it into separate areas and did it again. Two of the three areas (which were smaller than the third) aggregated correctly. The third I split into municipalities (since it had a few in it) and then aggregated each separately, apart from two, which refused to aggregate. The error message was not forthcoming, it just says "Background processing has encountered a serious error and is unable to continue. And then it allows me to send an error report to ESRI, which I have, though it's been almost innumerous times.

So I used grid index features and made a grid over one municipality and then split the data by that grid. I ended up having to do 5 x 5 km grids (making 42 index polygons) because anything bigger would not process properly. That actually sort of worked, except for five of the grids which would not. I tried vainly to do 'multipart to singlepart' which worked for some of them, though in this case, I had to further subdivide each 5x5 grid into 4 more indices. In that case, quite a few actually processed, but there is one or two stubborn grids which will not process at all and produce the same error.

I even went into each grid's data and used the editing toolbar to merge some of the polygons together manually, before using aggregate polygons.

Has someone else had similar trouble? Are there any workarounds or suggestions? Because I will otherwise have to repeat the process two or three more times (as it is a time-series project).

[image: A comparison screenshot of a subset of the data]

**edit:** I tried dissolve and it does sort-of do what we want, though is there any way to add a distance value to it like aggregate polygons has?

Comment: Dissolve will work better > http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000005n000000

Comment: If your dataset is huge Dissolve can use the Tiling for Large Datasets module > http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000014000000 (aggregate cannot)

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use dissolve because I don't have a field to dissolve by... or should it just be by FID or something?

Comment: Dissolve by Field is Optional

Comment: Any update on this? Aggregate Polygons is the most useful quick generalisation tool but it keeps falling over.
Might have to do the buffer minus buffer instead but that's hardly ideal.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/84693)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dissolve (Data Management)** is a better solution:

Dissolve will work better > http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000005n000000

(Dissolve by Field is Optional)

[image]

If your dataset is huge Dissolve can use the **Tiling for Large Datasets** module > http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000014000000 (aggregate cannot)

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make dissolve allow for a distance as in aggregate polygons?

Comment: Not without pushing up your cluster tolerance significantly, which would almost certainly give you undesired artefacts (like destroying the shape of your boundaries).  To mimic a disolve-over a distance operation you would need to buffer (with the dissolve option selected) and then de-buffer.  This is a workable approach in some circumstances but does significantly increase your vertex count (depending on your cluster tolerance) and can 'smooth' some sharp edges.  If you have the dissolve option turned on, buffer can also take advantage of the tiling for large datasets mentioned by Mapperz.