# Aggregate tool in ArcMap fails

Tags: arcmap, polygon, aggregation

I created vector polygons from a raster image and now I want to merge adjacent polygons based on a distance. I used the Aggregate Polygons (Cartography) tool after smoothing and running a Repair Geometry tool in ArcGIS.

However, the tool keeps failing. Dissolve tool suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24291/why-does-aggregate-polygons-consistently-error-out) doesn't work, because polygons don't have a common attribute. Could someone please help to sort this out or suggest a solution with other software such as QGIS or SAGA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solution:* I created a Personal Geodatabase and imported the shapefile as a feature class, then Aggregate polygons did the job perfectly. It seems like this tool doesn't work for shapefiles.